# Why is this array check for key failing?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, posix

```
declare -A page_array

if [ ! page_array${page_num+fooc} ] 
then
    echo "key $page_num not exists"
    page_array[$page_num]="something"
else
    echo "key $page_num  exists"
fi
```

Why do i get exists always.
I have just declared an array but not added any keys to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

```
if [ ! page_array${page_num+fooc} ]
```

It is an invalid expression (you are missing the `$` to call the variable, as well as the brackets to refer to an element --> `$var[index]`). Thus, the expression translates to:

```
if [ ! some_text ]
```

From `man test` we see that:

```
   ! EXPRESSION
          EXPRESSION is false
```

So that's why your expression is entering in the `else`: because it evaluates to false.

It is the same as saying the following, which returns "no":

```
[ ! a ] || echo "no"
```